# backbone js raw text posting

Tags: javascript, json, backbone.js

I need to post JSON data into a raw text format. I can post like key value pair. But fails to post like raw text format.

```
var clientslist = new ClientsList();
clientslist.fetch({
    data: $.param({data:'{"uid":19 ,"pn":0 }'}),
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json'
 });
```

Note that `clientlist()` is to server.

From the above code I can post JSON `{"id":123 ,"fl":0 }` in data key value. From server I can get it like php code `$_POST['data']`.

But for me it is just need to send the `JSON {"id":123 ,"fl":0 }` because from server it receive using php code `file_get_contents("php://input");`
How do I solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var clientslist = new ClientsList();
clientslist.fetch({
  data: JSON.stringify({ uid: 19, pn: 0 }),
  type: 'POST',
  dataType: 'json',
  contentType: 'application/json',
  processData: false
});
```